# Decimal to integer

Tags: functions

If we have a number $x$ such that $0 \leq x \leq 1,$ using only addition, subtraction, multiplication and division ops can we go from $x$ to $1$, without knowing what the original $x$ value is?

Example: Let $x = 0.5,$ we can reach $1$ by doing $2 * x.$ However, this only works for $x = 0.5$ and not other possible $x$ values such as $0.2, 0.35$ or $0.87.$

A basic solution is dividing $x$ by itself. Are there any other functions we can use such that $f(x) = 1?$

Comment: The function "dividing by itself" is just the function $f(x)=1$ for $x>0.$ A function in not concerned with the way it is computed, only with the result. $f(x)=1$ is the most basic such function.

Comment: The ceiling function $f(x)=\lceil x\rceil$ works for the interval $0\lt x\leq 1$.

Comment: Maybe $f(x)=x+(1-x)$ ?

Comment: There are infinitely many: $x-x+1$ or $2x-2x+1$ or $3x-3x+1$ or ..., but I have the feeling that this kind of answer is not satisfying for you.

Comment: "Dividing by itself" is no good since $x=0$ is included.

Comment: @FareedAF ... of course if you already know $1$ you are done, so there would be no need to do $x+(1-x)$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did not recognize that multiplying $0,5×2$ you are also dividing $\frac{x}{x}$ since multiplying by $2$ is the same as dividing bei $1/2$, so in fact you have with your operations only $\frac{x}{x}$ so with $0,35$ you multiply by $\frac{100}{35}$.

Answer (score 0):

What if $x=0$?  Then addition, subtraction, and multiplication can still only yield $0$ again.  And division by $0$ is undefined.  Therefore: starting with $x=0$ and using only addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division never yields the answer $1$.

Comment: Why not $0+1=1$ ?

Comment: If I do not know "1", then I cannot do $0+1$ of course.